# Gatling Verifying Decoded JWT token

Tags: java, scala, gatling

I'm trying to decode a JWT token returned, and check the sub claim for if it matches the username. But I can't seem to find the syntax to do so.

```
...
      .check(status.is(HttpResponseStatus.OK.code()))
      .check(jsonPath("$.access_token").saveAs("access_token"))
      .check(jsonPath("$.refresh_token").exists)
      .check(JWSObject.parse("${access_token}").getPayload.toJSONObject.get("sub").toString.substring("$username"))
```

I'm getting errors around it expecting a HttpCheck, is there a HTTPCheck for this type?

Thanks

Comment: Try to use `com.auth0.jwt.JWT` -> `JWT.decode(jwt).getClaim("sub").asString()`. Lib: i.e.: `com.auth0:java-jwt:3.4.0`

Comment: @Dumbo Thanks for the response, my main issue is how I would then check the output from this against another string, within the http request flow.

e.g 
.check decodedJWTString.equals("username")

Comment: why not `.check(JWT.decode(jwt).getClaim("sub").asString() == "username")` then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much exactly what .transform is for.
You extract the token with jsonPath, do a transform to get the sub, and then assert that it matches the username.

(I have not tried the actual jwt extract / validation)

```
.check(jsonPath("$.access_token").transform(jwt => JWT.decode(jwt).getClaim("sub").asString()).is("${username}")
```